# Getting the calling function in a custom ExcelDNA exception handler without MacroType

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I'm aware that there is the method shown in the [ErrorHAndler.dna example](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/ErrorHandler.dna):

```
private object ErrorHandler(object exceptionObject)
{
    ExcelReference caller = (ExcelReference)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfCaller);

    // Calling reftext here requires all functions to be marked IsMacroType=true, which is undesirable.
    // A better plan would be to build the reference text oneself, using the RowFirst / ColumnFirst info
    // Not sure where to find the SheetName then....
    string callingName = (string)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfReftext, caller, true);

    [...]

}
```

But has anyone determined how the issue described in the comment might be resolved?  I.e. is there a way to do this without setting `IsMacroType=true`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `IsMacroType=true` to get the caller (the first line in your sample works fine without it). As the comment in your sample indicates, if you want to build a text description for the range, you need to build it yourself from the Row/Column info in the `ExcelReference`. You can get the sheet name with a call to `XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlSheetNm, caller)`.